# Exclusive Selection List in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, monodevelop

Trying to create a questionnaire app in Xamarin and I'm having trouble achieving the functionality I want. I have a table view separated into sections with each section representing a question with multiple choice answers.

My intent is to have the user select an item in each section and have a checkmark appear beside their selection. They have the option to go back and change a selection, but they can only select one item per section (so the checkmark would move to their new selection in that section if they change it).

I found a good resource on Apple's Table View programming guide which seems to be what I want, but the problem is it's in Objective-C and I haven't been able to figure out how to do the same thing in C#. Here's the code example from Apple's guide:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    NSInteger catIndex = [taskCategories indexOfObject:self.currentCategory];
    if (catIndex == indexPath.row) {
        return;
    }
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:catIndex inSection:0];

    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (newCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        self.currentCategory = [taskCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:oldIndexPath];
    if (oldCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out Monotouch.Dialog: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog - it simplifies greatly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've spent the last couple days reading over and experimenting with MonoTouch.Dialog, but I don't think it will work for me in this case as I need a bit more control over the look and functionality of the view controller. Do you know how to accomplish what I'm trying to do with using the normal table view functionality?

Comment: Everyhing a table view can do, MT.Dialog can do. The key is to subclass the Elements. Trust me: it will be harder with plain vanilla table view.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on subclassing the Elements? And do you have any examples on the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I also need to add two buttons and several labels to the page, but couldn't get it to work how I wanted it. Using a StringElement with a delegate won't suffice as I need the buttons to look like default ios7 buttons to match the rest of my app.

Comment: I recently answered a somewhat similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21408374/1441667 If you still have problems  please post a comment.